# Are pthread read-write locks FIFO?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, readwritelock

In the library `pthread.h` are `pthread_rwlock_t` FIFO?

In the following example we have multiple threads. Imagine that every thread is guaranteed to run in order.

```
// Thread 1 - does a write lock
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock);

// Thread 2 - does a read but has to wait for 1
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock);

// Thread 3 - does a read but has to wait for 1
pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock);

// Thread 4 - does a write but has to wait for 1
pthread_rwlock_wrlock(&lock);

// Thread 1 - unlocks
pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock);

// who gets the lock?
```

After thread 1 releases the lock, who gets the lock? Is it guaranteed that thread 2 and 3 do? Or could it possibly be given to 4?

**Again, Imagine that every thread is guaranteed to run in order and thread 1 doesn't release the lock until all threads have tried to obtain the lock.**

Comment: I think the term FIFO is not applicable here. Threads aren't guaranteed to run in any order. And making assumptions about such things often leads to multi-threading issues. Your _imagine_ phrase makes no sense because it is actually the other way around: the thread that got lock is the one that will run.

Comment: You can call `join` on `thread 1` and guarantee that they wait for `thread 1` to finish. As for `"Threads aren't guaranteed to run in any order"` that's not necessarily true as it depends on the scheduling policy for the locks. If instead of a `read-write` lock we had a simple `mutex` we could guarantee that the threads run in sequential order by using a `FIFO` scheduling policy within the `mutex`.

Comment: There is a lock implementation at http://www.shlomifish.org/rwlock/ which does claim to be "first come first served", which per its docs would  run thread 2 and 3 in parallel once thread 1 releases, then once both of those were done would run thread 4.  I have not used it, and do not know how well it performs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some research and found [this document from the Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/6je9h032u/index.html) that explains the scheduling policy for pthread read-write locks.

> If the call to the pthread_rwlock_unlock() results in the read-write lock object becoming unlocked and there are multiple threads waiting to acquire the read-write lock object for writing, the scheduling policy is used to determine which thread acquires the read-write lock object for writing. If there are multiple threads waiting to acquire the read-write lock object for reading, the scheduling policy is used to determine the order in which the waiting threads acquire the read-write lock object for reading. **If there are multiple threads blocked on rwlock for both read locks and write locks, it is unspecified whether the readers acquire the lock first or whether a writer acquires the lock first.**

So in conclusion, they are not guaranteed to be FIFO.